# Find records that are not associated with other model in HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models 'Article' and 'List' both associated with HABTM association. I also have 'articles_lists' join table that has 'article_id' and 'list_id'. Now I would like to display all the articles that are not associated with any lists. Which is articles which does not have entry in 'articles_lists' table.

How can I achieve this in Rails 5. Please help

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
Article.includes(:articles_lists).where( :articles_lists => { :article_id => nil })
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it is giving me error :
ActionView::Template::Error (Can't join 'Article' to association named 'articles_lists'; perhaps you misspelled it?):

Comment: I just follow your information above, probably you can check your table name, probably article_lists ? just change my answer to follow your table name

Comment: Thank you it worked but with slight modification. I had to use singular for the join table in includes. i.e. Article.includes(:articles_list).where( :articles_lists => { :article_id => nil })